# Base Image causes cache bust in my docker file through Jenkine pipeline

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am observing cache bust at random times due to my base Python image when I build through Jenkins on my production server but not on my local machine which is a bit strange. This busting happens at random times, not always. I haven't found a pattern yet.

First few commands of my docker-file:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes apt-utils
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
```

Logs of the Build process (Build number:74) with no cache busting:

```
17:11:02 [workspace] Running shell script
17:11:02 + docker build -t ourapi:0.5.3 .
17:11:02 Sending build context to Docker daemon 232.4 kB

17:11:03 Step 1/14 : FROM python:2.7
17:11:03  ---> 26bddf7dbe1b
17:11:03 Step 2/14 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
17:11:03  ---> Using cache
17:11:03  ---> ec1bf9b7071a
17:11:03 Step 3/14 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
17:11:03  ---> Using cache
17:11:03  ---> df4b29a9466b
```

The next one busted the cache:

```
15:28:48 [workspace] Running shell script
15:28:48 + docker build -t ourapi:0.5.8 .
15:28:48 Sending build context to Docker daemon 243.2 kB

15:28:48 Step 1/14 : FROM python:2.7
15:28:50 2.7: Pulling from library/python
15:28:50 aa18ad1a0d33: Already exists
15:28:50 15a33158a136: Already exists
15:28:50 f67323742a64: Already exists
15:28:50 c4b45e832c38: Already exists
15:28:50 b71152c33fd2: Pulling fs layer
15:28:50 299c2fe5f47f: Pulling fs layer
15:28:50 6116a194f6b5: Pulling fs layer
15:28:50 3631cfa2c8cc: Pulling fs layer
15:28:50 3631cfa2c8cc: Waiting
15:28:50 6116a194f6b5: Verifying Checksum
15:28:50 6116a194f6b5: Download complete
15:28:50 b71152c33fd2: Verifying Checksum
15:28:50 b71152c33fd2: Download complete
15:28:51 299c2fe5f47f: Verifying Checksum
15:28:51 299c2fe5f47f: Download complete
15:28:51 b71152c33fd2: Pull complete
15:28:51 3631cfa2c8cc: Download complete
15:28:53 299c2fe5f47f: Pull complete
15:28:53 6116a194f6b5: Pull complete
15:28:53 3631cfa2c8cc: Pull complete
15:28:53 Digest: sha256:0cb0d5aa3cbb61374d83ce324e8ffee86cebc66a94c4d5ab08a67b650538d660
15:28:53 Status: Downloaded newer image for python:2.7
15:28:53  ---> 26bddf7dbe1b
```

Update: It was happening because a script within our Jenkins pipeline was running a cleanup script which removed these base images.

Comment: The commands you've provided would not replace the python image. What other commands are you running on your build server to clean or update your images? Can you verify the python image exists before the build runs and is identical to the prior run?

Comment: Also, do you have logs of the previous runs that show the image digest? Can you confirm that the image SHA256 is the same?

Comment: @BMitch there are other commands but they are just cloning the bitbucket repo before the build command. I cannot verify it for that specific build as I cleaned the server with "docker system prune". If it happens next time, I will do it. Build 76,78,79 all went fine. However, it does happen now and then.

Comment: @AndyShinn Build 75 has a different value than 71 (lass cache bust) but 71 and 70 have the same value whereas 70 was also a cache bust. In the middle, there were no cache busts. There was build failure but that shouldn't cause a cache bust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker cache relies on the prior layers existing on the server along with the cached layer with the same command being run. From the commands you've provided, you are not passing a `--pull` to the build command, so it is not the result of an upstream change to the python image. The two possible causes remaining are:

1. Most likely you have deleted the prior build and possibly base image too. This happens with a `docker rmi`, a `docker image prune`, or a `docker system prune` command.
2. You could have updated the python image on the build server. The logs you've provided don't show this, but I'm leaving it in in case your other cache busts don't show the "pulling" output. In that scenario, another build or an external process could pull a new copy of python:2.7 which would invalidate the cache of this build since the python:2.7 tag is now pointing to a new image id. You would see this new id in your logs.

Comment: I do run Docker system prune now and then. I thought it only removes the unnecessary images/containers. I even tested it after I faced this issue. I ran docker system prune and then attempted another build which did not bust the cache.

Comment: If your tag somehow gets removed or points to an image with a different set of layers, `docker system prune` will remove this cache. If you use `docker system prune -a` this will remove the image even if it is tagged.

Comment: I tried again few changes after some days and it again downloaded a new Python base image, repeating the rest of the docker commands. Updated the question with logs. I made sure that no docker system prune or docker image prune is run this time.

Comment: Do you have an image tagged `python:2.7` on your build server now? Did you have one before the build started? Do you have an untagged image with the old python checksum now?

Comment: nope, its Python 2 with an ID:fa8e55b2235d which is different than my last Python 2.7 ID. Just noticed that a colleague of mine is using the following in another project docker file (FROM python:2). Seems like thatś invalidating my cache.

Comment: He ran a build after mine. Seems like we are invalidating each otherś cache. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Those base images will be completely independent of each other, there shouldn't be any conflict. For some reason your base image tag is getting deleted or never getting created. I can't reproduce that behavior in my own environment (currently running 17.07 on Debian Linux). You may want to run your own tests on your build server, or try `docker pull python:2.7` to see if that stays through your builds. Note this means you'll miss future security patches without a process to refresh your base images.

Comment: I just ran a successful build but I do not see any tag Python 2.7. I have two Python tags on the build server (Python 2.7.13-onbuild)  and ( Python 2) both are two months old. However, I looked at the pattern and every time I got a cache bust, there was a build before on my colleague project and vice versa.   I don't get any cache bust when there is no build unless there is a build for my colleague project.

Comment: For testing, I'd recommend building by hand to avoid any other scripts being run by your build server. Without details of exactly what is being run in the other job, enough details to reproduce the issue, I'm afraid I can't be any more help.

Comment: I simulated the same behavior on my local machine (two projects with Python2 and Python 2.7 as the base image) but it didn't bust the cache.  You are right that my base images tag is never created or deleted. Seems to be something with the Jenkin pipeline or the server. will look into it further.

Comment: a script in the Jenkins was removing all the images so that was the culprit.